# Umbraco Beginning Razor - list all news items

Tags: events, date, razor, umbraco, nodes

Hi I have a node events and have 6 types 'eventItem' which are children. On my homepage I want to list all nodes of type eventItem and list the eventDate.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using razor you could do something like the following:

```
@{
    dynamic eventFolder = Library.NodeById(1234);

    <ul>
    @foreach (var event in eventFolder.Children)
    {
        <li>@event.eventDate.ToShortDateString() - @event.Name</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Obviously, replace "1234" with the actual Id of the event folder and then place the razor script inside a macro and put the macro on your home page's template and you should be good to go.